# Kendo Grid [object, Object] in editable cell when value is set as object

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am trying to set an object to an editable cell with dataTextField and dataValueField,
please see the plunker link...

When I try to add a pre-defined object to the grid, the values are not showing in the textbox, instead it shows [object, Object], what is the proper way to do it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/0Fx7hZyh0TYllducpfni?p=preview

```
  objectTextBoxEditor:  function (container, options) {
            $("<input id='\"job\" +   + \"'\" data-text-field=\"JobName\" data-value-field=\"JobId\"  name='" + options.field + "' class=\"k-input k-textbox\" type=\"text\" data-bind=\"value:Job\"/>").appendTo(container);}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that line:

```
dataSource.add({ Id: 1, Job:(viewModel.myjob === null) ? '' : viewModel.myjob.Job, Position:1 });
```

You are adding to grid new object. In `Job` field you have empty string or `viewModel.myjob.Job` value. On the top of file you are declaring it as `{ "JobName" : "Test", "JobId" : "1"}` so this is Object not string.

So probably you should change dataSource add function on `dataSource.add({ Id: 1, Job:(viewModel.myjob === null) ? '' : viewModel.myjob.Job.JobName, Position:1 });`

Answer (score 0):

In your `columns` setting you defined the second column to be bound to the `Job` field. This `Job` field is an Object containg both `JobId` and `JobName`. The grid can't display an object so it shows `[object Object]`.

The `dataTextField` and `dataValueField` you added to the column isn't working because the grid doesn't work like that. These settings work for dropdowns and such.

You can specify what field you want to show from the `Job` object by adding another level to the column's field, like this:

```
columns: [{"field":"Id","title":"ID", width: "100px"},
          {"field": "Job.JobName", title: "Job", width: "200px",
           editor: viewModel.objectTextBoxEditor,
           dataTextField: "JobName", dataValueField: "JobId"}]
```

I changed `"field": "Job"` to `"field": "Job.JobName"`.

Another solution is to specify a template and compose the cell contents yourself. You do this by adding a `template` field to the column, like this:

```
columns: [{"field":"Id","title":"ID", width: "100px"},
          {"field": "Job", title: "Job", width: "200px",
           editor: viewModel.objectTextBoxEditor,
           template: "ID: #: Job.JobId #, Name: #: Job.JobName #"}]
```

I added a `template` field that shows "ID: [JobId], Name: [JobName]".

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, but is there a way to bind dataTextField and dataValueField in a textbox control? If you ask why I want it that way, when I click the editable cell, a pop-up appears with the list of Jobs, when I select from there, the selected Job will be displayed on the editable cell's textbox... JobName as the dataTextfield and JobId as the dataValueField which I will be using when saving. Is that possible ?